# StackOverflowError when trying to connect to MySQL

Tags: java, mysql, database

I am trying to establish a connection between a Java-based project and a MySQL database. From what I can tell, the database seems to be fine (the expected information is stored in its columns). However, when I use the Java program to open a connection I obtain a StackOverflow error, which I am not sure why is happening:

```
Exception in thread "Thread-2" java.lang.StackOverflowError
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:361)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:411)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:335)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:763)
    at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:142)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:467)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$100(URLClassLoader.java:73)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:368)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:362)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:361)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:335)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:763)
    at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:142)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:467)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$100(URLClassLoader.java:73)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:368)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:362)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:361)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:335)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:763)
    at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:142)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:467)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$100(URLClassLoader.java:73)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:368)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:362)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:361)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:335)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.NonRegisteringDriver.connect(NonRegisteringDriver.java:334)
    at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:664)
    at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:270)
```

I have taken several actions to solve this issue but none of them have worked. Among them, I have successfully run the example that is described in [MySQLJavaTutorials](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/MySQLJava/article.html), which makes me think that this issue is not because of either the JDBC connector, the operating system, the database itself or the MySQL server version.

However, I have noticed that if I completely delete the database (by executing DROP DATABASE mydatabase) I get the exact same exception, as if the database had never existed in the first place. This also happens if I alter the name of the database to one that does not exist on purpose. My machine uses:

> Operating System: Ubuntu 64 bits 14.04.5 LTS
>
> MySQL server version: 5.5.58
>
> Eclipse Oxygen 2
>
> Java 1.8.0_151

Do you have any idea of why this is happening?

While the project I am working on is rather complex, the location of the call where I invoke the function is:

```
 @Override
    public void openDBConnection() throws Exception {
        //this method establish a database connection
        try {
            // This will load the MySQL driver, each DB has its own driver
            Class.forName(driver);

            // Setup the connection with the DB
            
            //////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
            String connection = "jdbc:mysql://" + host + "/" + dbname + "?"
                    + "user=" + user + "&password=" + passwd + "&useSSL=false";
            System.out.println(connection);
            connect = DriverManager.getConnection(connection);
            //////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
           

        } catch (ClassNotFoundException | SQLException e) {
            throw e;
        } finally {
        }
    }
```

The exception is thrown at the `connect = DriverManager.getConnection(connection);` line. The connection string that I obtain is fine. Actually, I am quite sure that this is not related to the `JDBC connection` because if I miswrite the driver´s name then I get a reasonable error instead of it.

Comment: Showing the exception is good, but the code that generated it is important as well.

Comment: This doesn't sound like it is the database that is the problem at all. I'd say the error is in the code prior to or at the very first point of starting to make the connection. It definitely isn't forming a connection though - as your renaming/dropping tests indicate.

Comment: Both of you are right, I have added some of the code and have tested with Wireshark that there are no MySQL traces sent

Comment: Which mysql library you are using in your application?

Comment: The stacktrace does not contain any mysql lines.  So I am guessing that JDBC did not find the mysql JDBC implementation.